# Are tile bonuses counted twice if 2 new words are formed?

Tags: scrabble

An example:

```
  O
 O?
```

There is a triple letter tile to the right of the bottom O, indicated with a *?*.

If I place an **X** on it, making the words OX (vertical) and OX (horizontal), do I score 50 points (scoring the tile twice) or 34 (scoring it once)?

Comment: Spelling OX or AX (and now ZA or KI/QI thanks to the updates) going multiple directions on any sort of bonus tile is pretty awesome if you can pull it off.  It might not give you as many points as a bingo, but its certainly an attractive option.

Comment: This is pretty much how I play. You'd be surprised how well you can do by catching a triple-letter tile twice.

Answer (score 26):

**Yes**, you score it twice as long as the double/triple letter/word tile was covered up by your current play.

From the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/scrabble/en_US/scoringRules.cfm):

> When two or more words are formed in the same play, each is scored. The common letter is counted (with full premium value, if any) for each word. (See Turns 3, 4 and 5 in the Scoring Examples