# Double/triple space scoring

Tags: scrabble

If you play a letter on a double or triple space and it makes 2 different words going in 2 directions, do you get double/triple points for BOTH words??

Comment: Very similar to https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44481/word-premium-applies-to-2-words, but the question is a bit different.

Comment: It does seem to be an exact duplicate of [Are tile bonuses counted twice if 2 new words are formed?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3545/are-tile-bonuses-counted-twice-if-2-new-words-are-formed) though.